# How to reset a written file w/ Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm working on a linux kernel/module.
I was wondering how to reset a module that I have written onto.

```
static int dev_release(struct inode *inodep, struct file *filep) {
    primeCount = 0;
    printk(KERN_INFO "mydriver: released\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I would like *filep to be a new file with nothing on it.

Comment: `*filep to be a new file with nothing on it.` - What do you mean by "nothing on it"? Should the file not exist at all? Or should the file's content be empty? Also, by `*filep` in the question you mean a file which is **created by your module**, don't you?

Comment: yes the file was created by the module. I would like the content to be empty

Comment: It is you (as an author of the module) who maintain the file's content. So, whenever you want, you may empty its content (e.g. set size of the buffer, representing the file, to 0). What is a problem? Or do you want to let user to empty file's content (with using some sort of request to your driver)?